# C++: run-time check failure; stack around variable corrupted; also off by one error

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, runtime-error

I have spent over an hour on trying to find the error in this insertion sort code I wrote. The problem is that even though it sorts the array, it moves its values up by one place. For example, input[2] gives 2 instead of 1. Also afterward I get the run-time error: "stack around variable was corrupted." It's probably a looping error, but I am unable to find it. Thank you for your help.

```
//Haris
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void insertionSort(int*, int);

int main(){

    int input[10] = { 8, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 10, 9, 4, 7 };
    insertionSort(input, 10);
    cout << input[2] << endl;// results are off by one, so input[2] is 2 instead of 1
    system("pause");
}

void insertionSort(int input[], int size){

    int temp = 0;//supposed minimum that is being checked
    int temp1;//value of array that is being replaced by temp
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        if (input[i] > input[i + 1]){
            temp = input[i + 1];
            int location = i + 1; //location of the supposed minimum
            for (int j = i + 1; j > 0; j--){
                if (temp < input[j - 1]){
                    temp1 = input[j - 1];
                    input[j - 1 ] = temp;
                    input[location] = temp1;

                    //cout << "[j-1] is " << j - 1 << endl;
                    //cout << "input[j-1] is " << input[j - 1] << endl;
                    //cout << "input[location] is " << input[location] << endl;
                    //cout << "location is " << location << endl;

                    location = (j - 1);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using valgrind?

Comment: `if (input[i] > input[i + 1]){` if input is of size 10 then `input[i+1]` will attempt to access `input[10]` which is out of the bounds for input.

Comment: @shuttle87: if `size` is 10, `i` will never get to 10, but `i+1` will, which is out of bounds.

Comment: @ScottHunter, ha off by one in my comment too, I edited the comment.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt why is it not insertion sort? I loop forward until i find an inversion value; in that loop, then I loop backward until the inversion value is moved to its place in the initial corrected array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going out of bounds here when `i == size - 1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if (input[i] > input[i + 1]){
    //                  ^^^^^^^ i + 1 == size -> out of bounds
```

Change it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

In the outer loop you are accessing out of bound memory area.
Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void insertionSort(int*, int);

int main()
{

    int input[10] = { 8, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 10, 9, 4, 7 };
    insertionSort(input, 10);
    cout << input[2] << endl;// results are off by one, so input[2] is 2 instead of 1
    system("pause");
}

void insertionSort(int input[], int size)
{
    int temp = 0;//supposed minimum that is being checked
    int temp1;//value of array that is being replaced by temp
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
        if (input[i] < input[i - 1]){
            temp = input[i];
            int location = i; //location of the supposed minimum
            for (int j = i; j > 0; j--){
                if (temp < input[j - 1]){
                    temp1 = input[j - 1];
                    input[j - 1 ] = temp;
                    input[location] = temp1;

                    //cout << "[j-1] is " << j - 1 << endl;
                    //cout << "input[j-1] is " << input[j - 1] << endl;
                    //cout << "input[location] is " << input[location] << endl;
                    //cout << "location is " << location << endl;

                    location = (j - 1);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```